# Finding the Matrix of a Linear Transformation $T$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be the linear space of functions on $\mathbb{R}$ spanned by the functions $\{1,x,e^{x},xe^{x}\}$. Define a linear map by

$$T: V \to V ; T(f)=f'$$
where $f'$ denotes the derivative of $f$.

Now my problem is when the derivative of $xe^{x}$ which is $xe^{x} + e^{x}$  comes about. How do I write this as combination of the basis vectors?

Comment: You already have.

Comment: Just to make amd's comment more explicit, it is $1 \cdot xe^x + 1 \cdot e^x$

Comment: 1 ($x e^x$) + 1 $(e^x)$ ? or in a vector form, $[0,0,1,1]^T$ using the basis as you've ordered it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a a space spanned by $\{1,x,e^x,xe^x\}$, so this is the basis we are working with here.

$$ \frac{d}{dx}(xe^x)=xe^x+e^x=1(xe^x)+1(e^x).$$
That is, it is $1$ times the basis vector $xe^x$ plus one times the other basis vector $e^x$. I hope that is clearer now.